# WP7 set Image to source behind a HttpBasicAuthenticator

Tags: silverlight, authentication, windows-phone-7, http-authentication

i am trying to set an image in a Windows Phone 7 App, there is a problem thoug, the url where the image is located required Authenticator, i have a valid username and password, but i have no idea how to load the image thoug an URI with the Authenticator?

```
        ProfileImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(userObject.ProfileImage));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you can use a authentication url, ie. `http://username:password@domain.tld/image.png` then you need to download the image locally first, and then load it afterwards.

You could write a custom handler for it, that downloads it to the Isolated Storage, and then automatically updates the UI, while using a fallback image (typically blank) while loading it.

Comment: Assigning http://username:password@domain.tld/image.png to Image's Source doesn't work on Silverlight 5.  What local storage can I use on Silverlight 5 to save the image?  Mine app isn't WP.  It's a standard in browser SL5 app.

Comment: I have no idea, ask your own question with the proper tags.